# Once the form has been submiited via an iframe, how can we fetch the result (just a value eg price) displayed in iframe to the parent html page?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, iframe

I have made a html page and calling a form in iframe. Once I have submitted that form it returns me some values like price .

How can we fetch these values displayed in iframe on the parent html page using php or javascript?

Comment: This is my html code :<html>
<body>
Its now a html file
<iframe width="100%" height="500px" src="http://67.222.157.154:1900/3Dpart/" name="iframe_a"></iframe>
</body>
</html>

Comment: And why are you using an iFrame ?

Comment: is the iFrame in a different domain? if so, the simple answer is, you can't

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: I have a html page calling an iframe which has a form in it. Once i click submit, result is displayed in the iframe displaying price and time. I want to fetch those values from iframe in to the parent html page.

Comment: Are you displaying the price in a element inside iframe, which you want to access from parent window?

Comment: I am using an iFrame because the code is running on different windows server and i want to fetch the values on a html file running on a linux server @JaromandaX

Comment: http://67.222.157.154:1900/3Dpart/     @DeepakBiswal this is an open source code which is running on .net and pages are displayed via PHP. This is running on windows server. I am not clear about your question